# bash open .html file not in browser but with $editor

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I want to open all of my html/css/js etc. not in the Browser by typing `open example.html`, but with my default Editor. I did create the `alias EDITOR` already, but it does not work with every kind of file.

How to fix that?

Comment: it's not `alias`, it should be `export`. `EDITOR` is an environment variable.

Comment: There's the additional problem that `open` doesn't use `EDITOR` to choose the editor to open (we're talking about OS X, right? I added that tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the actual behavior you're looking for, you will probably want one of the following, from the `open` man page:

```
 -e  Causes the file to be opened with /Applications/TextEdit

 -t  Causes the file to be opened with the default text editor, as deter-
     mined via LaunchServices

 -f  Reads input from standard input and opens the results in the default
     text editor.  End input by sending EOF character (type Control-D).
     Also useful for piping output to open and having it open in the
     default text editor.

 -W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were
     already open) have exited.  Use with the -n flag to allow open to
     function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment variable.
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html): `man open`

I see three options:

- `-a`

> -a application
>           Specifies the application to use for opening the file
>   
>   `open -a SomeEditor file.html`

- `-e`

> Causes the file to be opened with /Applications/TextEdit
>   
>   `open -e file.html`

- `-t`

> Causes the file to be opened with the default text editor, as determined via LaunchServices
>   
>   `open -t file.html`

Answer (score 1):

If you use TextMate or Sublime Text, you can use `mate` or `subl`. You can create aliases like this for other editors:

```
alias wrang="open -a TextWrangler"
```

`open -t` opens files in the default application for `public.plain-text` files. You can change it by adding a line like this to a [duti](http://duti.org/) configuration file:

```
com.macromates.TextMate.preview public.plain-text all
```

Comment: I use an alias for that now and I'm very happy with it. For me its just `alias s=open -a Sublimetext`. That is what I really needed.